# Understanding a call of "console.log(typeof null);" in a javascript console

Tags: javascript, console, chromium

I've just executed the following code in a Chromium **javascript console**:

```
console.log(typeof null);
```

The result is seen in the following screen capture:

[image]

I am just wondering what the greyed `<- undefined` line means. Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`undefined` It's the last statement's return value.

```
> 5
5
> "Hello World"
"Hello World"
> (function(){ return 6})();
6
```

Whenever a function in JavaScript does not explicitly return anything, it returns `undefined` by default.

To sum up the process, `object` is the result of your `console.log(typeof null)` call. Your code ran, logged `object` to the console then printed the return value of the function call which is `undefined`.

This is probably the result of how `eval` works. The console in the developer tools in chrome probably runs `eval` on your code. `eval` returns the value of the last statement/expression you put in it

```
> eval(5);
5
```

(Note: I know this is fairly obvious, but when using eval in an example I feel the need to mention that while a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) is an excellent use case for `eval` we must remember that [eval is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx))

Comment: "This is probably the result of how `eval` works" Or... the `console.log` function returns undefined? I'm confused why it's important that `eval` might be involved.

Comment: Perhaps you could include that the first line (`object`) is _not_ the return value but the output of `console.log(typeof null)`. I took a while before I realized.

Comment: @Xymostech You're typing the expression "5" and it somehow types "5" to you, why does that happen? I think that `eval` is an essential part of how the chrome developr tools console works being a Read-Eval-Print-Loop and all. When you're typing code into the console it gets eval'd. While I started by saying _what_ is happening, I felt it was important to explain _how_.

Comment: Ah. It appears that the ordering of your statements is confusing me. I read it as "functions return undefined by default, this is caused because of `eval`", not "functions return undefined by default. The way the console works is via `eval`". Makes more sense now!

Comment: @Xymostech I hope the edit makes it more clear, thank you for your help